# Transformations Linear Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation defined by

$T(x,y) = (-6x -3y; -4x -2y)$

Find a vector $w$ that is not in the image of $T$.

Cannot work this out please help me.

Answer (score 4):

$$T\binom xy=\binom{-6x-3y}{-4x-2y}=\binom{\frac32t}t$$

with $\;t=-4x-2y\;$, thus *any* vector not of this form won't be in the image of $\;T\;$, for example

$$\binom 11\;,\;\;\binom1 3\;,\;\;\binom{\sqrt2}5\;,\ldots$$

Comment: tried inputting all of those answers, but its being marked as incorrect

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be a Vector (it looks like a Point) - thats what the system is telling me

Comment: I don't know what "answer" are you talking about: I showed that any point in the image is of the form as in the first line, and thne gave you three examples of vector that don't have that form. What "the system" says is irrelevant to me: the answer is correct *unless* I made a mistake.